# Where should the string literals during the checking for equality, left-side or right-side?

Tags: java

I used in my code `"".equals(val)` but if it is `"".equals("abc")`

then, what should be the correct expression for it.

Comment: Your question is neither clear nor make sense. What you are going to achieve with second option?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The only way to do it your way round is if you are comparing to a potentially null value and don't want to test for it or be hit by an NPE.

Comment: You should never write `"".equals("abc")`, because the result is statically predictable.

Comment: Not able to understand What are you looking for? Can you please post your code and edit your question?

Comment: in case of two string literals it doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

Having a string literal on left-hand side of expression will not generate the NullPointerException.

`if(a !=null && a.equals("value"))` you can replace with `if("value".equals(a))`.

PS

Having the constant on the left-hand side is cleaner approach as prevent from making errors. It is can be called as [yoda condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Comment: it can be perfect candidate to do pmd check

Comment: @Orion, Its already there names as `UnusedNullCheckInEquals`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"abc".equals("def")
```

is equivalent to

```
"def".equals("abc")
```

if that's what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two string literals? Just use the boolean constant, you know they're the same (or not) already.

Comparing a string literal and a string variable? `literal.equals(variable)`. This prevents null pointer exception.

Two variables? Check for null, then `nullCheckedVariable.equals(otherVariable)`.